# Handsontable - Unable to keep html element created by a custom renderer visible

Tags: handsontable

I am using the open source version of handsontable (version 0.29.2). I created a custom renderer that creates a hidden SPAN element/icon on every row.  When input fails validation, I use jQuery to programmatically unhide/show the SPAN tag/icon so that it appears in the right-hand side of the cell. It works great, but unfortunately when I enter an invalid value into another cell, the icon from the first cell disappears.  The preferred behavior is to have all of the icons visible in cells where a validation issue exists.

Question: Is there a way to keep all of the icons visible?

If this is not possible, is there a different way in handsontable to display an image after validation?  As you can see from the code below (and my jsfiddle example), I am not using the built-in handsontable validation hooks.  With the built-in validation, I can't add an icon like I want - I can only override the default style of an invalid cell by using invalidCellClassName.

I have created a simple example with instructions demonstrating my issue:
http://jsfiddle.net/4g3a5kqc/15/

```
var data = [
    ["1", "abc"],
    ["2", "def"],
    ["3", "ghi"],
    ["4", "jkl"]
],
container = document.getElementById("example"),
hot1;    

// This function is a custom renderer that creates a hidden SPAN element/  
// icon.  In this example, when a user changes the value, the SPAN element
// icon will appear.
function customRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties)             {
    td.innerHTML = value +
        '<span id="account-code-error-' + row + '-' + col + '" class="account-code-error ' +
        'glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign text-warning jzb-icon-md pull-right" ' +
        'style="font-size: large; cursor: pointer; display: none;"></span>';
}

var hot1 = new Handsontable(container, {
data: data,
rowHeaders: true,
colHeaders: true,
stretchH: 'all',
cells: 
    function (row, col, prop) {
        var cellProperties = {};
        if (col == 0) {
            cellProperties.renderer = customRenderer;
        }
        return cellProperties;
    }    
});

hot1.addHook('afterChange', afterChange);

// Show the SPAN tag with the icon
// in the right-hand side of the cell.
function afterChange(changes, source) {
    console.log(changes, source);

if (source == 'edit' || source == 'autofill') {
    $.each(changes,
        function (index, element) {
            var change = element;
            var rowIndex = change[0];
            var columnIndex = change[1];
            var oldValue = change[2];
            var newValue = change[3];

            console.log(oldValue, newValue, rowIndex, columnIndex, change);

            if (columnIndex != 0) {
                return;
            }

            if (newValue >= 0) {
                return;
            }

            var cellProperties = hot1.getCellMeta(rowIndex, hot1.propToCol(columnIndex));

            var td = hot1.getCell(rowIndex, columnIndex, true);
            var span = td.getElementsByTagName("span");
            $("#" + span[0].id).show();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to customRenderer() being called after every change we have to store somewhere cells with spans visible and check for it at the rendering. On the other hand if the span should not be visible (input is valid) we need to remove it from the array of cells wit visible spans. Working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/8vdwznLs/

```
var data = [
    ["1", "abc"],
    ["2", "def"],
    ["3", "ghi"],
    ["4", "jkl"]
],
container = document.getElementById("example"),
hot1,
visibleSpans = [];    

// This function is a custom renderer that creates a hidden SPAN element/  
// icon.  In this example, when a user changes the value, the SPAN element
// icon will appear.
function customRenderer(instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties)             {
if (visibleSpans.indexOf(td) > -1) {
    td.innerHTML = value +
        '<span id="account-code-error-' + row + '-' + col + '" class="account-code-error ' +
        'glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign text-warning jzb-icon-md pull-right" ' +
        'style="font-size: large; cursor: pointer;"></span>';
} else {
    td.innerHTML = value +
        '<span id="account-code-error-' + row + '-' + col + '" class="account-code-error ' +
        'glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign text-warning jzb-icon-md pull-right" ' +
        'style="font-size: large; cursor: pointer; display: none;"></span>';
}
}

var hot1 = new Handsontable(container, {
data: data,
rowHeaders: true,
colHeaders: true,
stretchH: 'all',
cells: 
    function (row, col, prop) {
        var cellProperties = {};
        if (col == 0) {
            cellProperties.renderer = customRenderer;
        }
        return cellProperties;
    }    
});

hot1.addHook('afterChange', afterChange);

// Show the SPAN tag with the icon
// in the right-hand side of the cell.
function afterChange(changes, source) {
    console.log(changes, source);

if (source == 'edit' || source == 'autofill') {
    $.each(changes,
        function (index, element) {
            var change = element;
            var rowIndex = change[0];
            var columnIndex = change[1];
            var oldValue = change[2];
            var newValue = change[3];
            var td = hot1.getCell(rowIndex, columnIndex, true);

            console.log(oldValue, newValue, rowIndex, columnIndex, change);

            if (columnIndex != 0) {
                return;
            }

            if (newValue >= 0) {
              var indexOfSpan = visibleSpans.indexOf(td);
                if (indexOfSpan > -1) {
                  visibleSpans.splice(indexOfSpan, 1);
                  hot1.render();
                  return;
                }
              return;
            }

            var cellProperties = hot1.getCellMeta(rowIndex, hot1.propToCol(columnIndex));

            visibleSpans.push(td);
            var span = td.getElementsByTagName("span");
            span[0].setAttribute('style', '');
        });
    }
}
```